# ggplot2 position_stack(vjust) with absolute unit rather than proportional

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a stacked barplot and I want to label the value of each bar inside the bar. Here is an example :

```
diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  count(low_price = price < 3000) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  aes(
    x = cut, 
    y = n, 
    fill = low_price
    ) +
  geom_col() + 
  geom_text(
    aes(label = n),
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.8)
    )
```

I'm using `position_stack(vjust = 0.8)` to adjust the vertical position of the label within the bar. The problem is the adjustment is a percentage: it actualy places the label at 80% of the total height of the bar. 
I would like to have something similar in absolute unit: for example -1 cm or - 30 px from the top of each bar. Is there a way to do that ?

Sorry for bad english and thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using the `geom_text` `vjust` rather than the `position_stack` `vjust`. It isn't a customizable absolute unit like you ask for, but it is relative to the size of the text, which is an absolute size in point size, so it is not proportional to the size of the bar.

```
diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  count(low_price = price < 3000) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  aes(
    x = cut, 
    y = n, 
    fill = low_price
    ) +
  geom_col() + 
  geom_text(
    aes(label = n),
    position = position_stack(),
    vjust = 1.2
    )
```

[image]